# Activity loosing data after coming back from Camera Activity

Tags: android, android-camera, google-play-services

I have an app where I should fill data on some edittexts or spinners. After that I have some buttons where I should take some pictures, sometimes there's 2 or 3 pictures. Im using a Camera Intent.

The problem is that SOMETIMES just in SOME PHONES, when the app comesback from Camera app it deletes all data filled on the views, and it deletes the pictures already taken. So it crush the activity.

I'm pretty sure its not the orientation, since IM using this on the manifest.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="screenLayout|orientation|screenSize">
```

I have nothing on the error log. One solution is when I delete data from Google Play Services or I unistall it and reinstall again. This fix the problem for sometime and then it happens again.

I dont know what else could it be. On the activity Im using Camera and Im accesing User location.

Answer (score 4):

Camera app takes a lot of memory and on low-end devices with less memory system might kill your app to free some memory.

`android:configChanges` is more of a hack rather than a correct solution, it does not prevent a case as described above.

You should implement correctly activity life time cycle functions, by saving instance state in `onSaveInstanceState` and recreating it in `onCreate`. There is no other way around.

To test such cases, go to developer settings and disable applications in background. This way each time you will click on home button of your device, your app will be killed, and going back to it it will be recreated.